# Any Device Native features not available via NativeScript (Angular 2)?

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

While trying to compare between ReactNative vs NativeScript, I see that ReactNative currently does not provide support for NFC.

**Is there any such Device Native features currently not supported by NativeScript ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript exposes the underlying platform's frameworks to you dynamically at runtime, so any framework or API available on the underlying platform is exposed to you in JavaScript. For example, [here are some of NativeScript's docs on what the resulting JS looks like for iOS.](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/marshalling/Marshalling-Overview.html)

One of the main reasons to use NativeScript is to write a single codebase that runs on multiple platforms, so instead of calling platform-specific APIs directly in your application, you'll want to use a NativeScript plugin which coalesces the disparate iOS and Android APIs into a single platform-agnostic interface that your app can consume.

Many such plugins have already been created by Telerik and contributed by the NativeScript community. If there's specific device functionality you're interested in, you can check if a plugin already exists on NPM or on [Telerik's page of verified plugins](http://plugins.telerik.com/nativescript).